# POST Transaction in shopify

Tags: shopify

I am also doing to create transaction below is my code

```
$dataem  = array('transactions'=>array('kind'=>'sale','status'=>'success'));
$urls = 'https://'.'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.':'.'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.'@storeName.myshopify.com/admin/orders/xxxxxxxid/transactions.json';

$data_string = json_encode($dataem);

$headers = array(
"Content-Type: application/json",
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-Length:" . strlen($data_string));

$handler = curl_init($urls);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handler, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$responses = curl_exec($handler);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($responses);
```

and its shows result {"errors":{"transaction":"Required parameter missing or invalid"}}

Answer (score 1):

See the Shopify API docs for [creating a transaction here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/transaction#create):

> ```
> POST /admin/orders/#{id}/transactions.json
> {   
>     "transaction": {
>         "kind": "capture"
>     }
> }
> ```

You've got 'transactions' instead of 'transaction'. Also, the `status` is returned in the response, you shouldn't specify it in the request.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you created a transaction for an order. Remember you have to pass `"external"` as the `source`. Otherwise you will get an error saying `sale is not a valid transaction`.

```
POST https://{your_store}.myshopify.com/admin/api/{api_version}/orders/{order_id}/transactions.json

{
    "transaction": {
        "kind": "sale",
        "gateway": "Your Gateway name",
        "status": "success",
        "source": "external"
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/can-not-to-create-transaction-for-order-using-api/td-p/508614)